# Select from mysql table WHERE field='$array'?

Tags: php, mysql, select, arrays

If I have an array of say, some ID's of users. How could i do something like this:

```
$array = array(1,40,20,55,29,48);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `myField`='$array'";
```

Is there a simple way to do this, I thought about looping through array items and then building up one big "WHERE -- OR -- OR -- OR" statement but i thought that might be a bit slow for large arrays.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `myField` IN (1,40,20,55,29,48)";
```

you can use `implode(",", $array)` to get the list together from the array.

Answer (score 11):

You want to use `IN`:

```
WHERE `myfield` IN (1,40,20,55,29,48)
```

Use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to construct the string:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `myField` IN (" . implode(',', $array) . ")";
```

Comment: So would i do "IN ($array)" ?

Comment: No, use implode to construct the string.