# Create SQL query that takes an array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php and need to do a bunch of select statements on the same table and column and get the rows that match those values.

I have all the values I'm searching on in an array and right now I'm just looping and doing a select statement on each one separately. How could I put this all into one select statement and ditch the loop?

Right now it's like this:

```
for (yaddah yaddah yahhah){
    SELECT * FROM scan WHERE order=var[$i];
}
```

Comment: Nearly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382831/select-from-mysql-table-where-fieldarray posted just 30 minutes before.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I looked but didn't see that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `IN` to specify a list of values :

```
select * 
from scan
whenre order IN (1, 5, 46, 78)
```

And you can get such a list using the [`implode`][1] function :

```
$array = array(1, 5, 46, 78);
$list_str = implode(', ', $array);
// $list_str is now "1, 5, 46, 78"

$query = "select *
from scan
where order IN ($list_str)
";
```

After, in your PHP script, it's only a matter of fetching several lines instead of only one.

Comment: Thanks, this is much simpler than creating a temp table like I was told somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IN` and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `scan` WHERE `order` IN (" . implode(',', $array) . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out SQL's [In Operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)