# Mysql select statement using php array

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have an array as following

```
$sql_column_headings = array("Week Period", "Comments Approved", "Comment Replies");
```

Number of items in the array is not fixed as they are selected from a 'select multiple lists'.

[image]

The list may consist more than 3 items and any number of items may be selected. Then submit button is pressed.
How can I create a select statement where the column headings are taken from the array mentioned above. Thanks.

Comment: MySQL IN Clause https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: What's your target? You really want to have a these array values being the column header in the mysql result set or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select from mysql table WHERE field='$array'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382831/select-from-mysql-table-where-field-array)

Comment: I want the array values as column header  in the mysql result set @AlexOdenthal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql_column_headings = array("Week Period", "Comments Approved", "Comment Replies");

    $columns = implode(",",$sql_column_headings);

    $sql = "SELECT '$columns' FROM table_name";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$sql_column_headings = array("Week Period", "Comments Approved", "Comment Replies");

    $itemStr = implode(",",$sql_column_headings);

    $qry = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE field_name IN('$itemStr')";

    $resSet = mysql_query($qry);
```

Check this,
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp

Comment: In this case, you have to make sure that string will pass like in IN clause ('str1','str2','str3')